# How to use UUID with unprivileged user on Postgres?

Tags: docker, postgresql-10

How make a default value for uuid rows?, the `uuid_generate_v4()` function works only if the `uuid-ossp` extension is enabled but can not enable.

```sql
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
CREATE EXTENSION
postgres=# SELECT uuid_generate_v4();
           uuid_generate_v4           
--------------------------------------
 929d5e41-d7a8-408a-b0e9-feecf10d853d
(1 row)
...
demo=> select uuid_generate_v4();
ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist
LINE 1: select uuid_generate_v4();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
demo=> CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "uuid-ossp"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
```

Comment: After you created the extension you might need to grant execute privilege on the function in the extension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Top of all, it doesn't say it is unavailable to use but it isn't allowed to create an extension with an unprivileged user. During the Docker image composition you should create and / or enable required extensions.

The official postgres docker images will execute script which placed under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder.

If you are using official image as a base image (recommended) you just create an `.sh` file, grant executable flag (chmod 755), and add this to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder.

Hopefully it will work:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname="$POSTGRES_DB"<<-EOSQL
   CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
EOSQL
```

---

### Edit

You don't have to place complicated `.sh`-scripts into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`. It is also possible to put `.sql`-files there, which will be executed with the superuser.

It simplifies the placed script to:

```sql
   CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

(`IF EXISTS` doesn't hurt but also doesn't help, because the initialization will only executed on a empty database.)

Comment: You can also place `.sql`-files there. I think, that they will be executed with the privileged `postgres`-user. It is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

i run sql like below not work:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
SELECT uuid_generate_v4();
```

so i try to install the uuid manualy:
first go to the postgresql lib dir,make sure uuid-ossp.so exists.

```
cd /usr/local/lib/postgresql
ls uuid-ossp.so
```

then run the sql in /usr/share/postgresql/extension/uuid-ossp--1.1.sql

```
CREATE FUNCTION uuid_nil()
RETURNS uuid
AS '$libdir/uuid-ossp.so', 'uuid_nil'
IMMUTABLE STRICT LANGUAGE C PARALLEL SAFE;

CREATE FUNCTION uuid_ns_dns()
RETURNS uuid
AS '$libdir/uuid-ossp.so', 'uuid_ns_dns'
IMMUTABLE STRICT LANGUAGE C PARALLEL SAFE;

CREATE FUNCTION uuid_ns_url()
RETURNS uuid
AS '$libdir/uuid-ossp.so', 'uuid_ns_url'
IMMUTABLE STRICT LANGUAGE C PARALLEL SAFE;

CREATE FUNCTION uuid_ns_oid()
RETURNS uuid
AS '$libdir/uuid-ossp.so', 'uuid_ns_oid'
IMMUTABLE STRICT LANGUAGE C PARALLEL SAFE;

CREATE FUNCTION uuid_ns_x500()
RETURNS uuid
AS '$libdir/uuid-ossp.so', 'uuid_ns_x500'
IMMUTABLE STRICT LANGUAGE C PARALLEL SAFE;

CREATE FUNCTION uuid_generate_v1()
RETURNS uuid
AS '$libdir/uuid-ossp.so', 'uuid_generate_v1'
VOLATILE STRICT LANGUAGE C PARALLEL SAFE;

CREATE FUNCTION uuid_generate_v1mc()
RETURNS uuid
AS '$libdir/uuid-ossp.so', 'uuid_generate_v1mc'
VOLATILE STRICT LANGUAGE C PARALLEL SAFE;

CREATE FUNCTION uuid_generate_v3(namespace uuid, name text)
RETURNS uuid
AS '$libdir/uuid-ossp.so', 'uuid_generate_v3'
IMMUTABLE STRICT LANGUAGE C PARALLEL SAFE;

CREATE FUNCTION uuid_generate_v4()
RETURNS uuid
AS '$libdir/uuid-ossp.so', 'uuid_generate_v4'
VOLATILE STRICT LANGUAGE C PARALLEL SAFE;

CREATE FUNCTION uuid_generate_v5(namespace uuid, name text)
RETURNS uuid
AS '$libdir/uuid-ossp.so', 'uuid_generate_v5'
IMMUTABLE STRICT LANGUAGE C PARALLEL SAFE
```

then confirm again,it works!!!

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
SELECT uuid_generate_v4();
```